# Dev environment for Prestashop (OVH web provider) always redirect to "old" installation

Tags: prestashop, ovh

I have:

1. Created an **A** entry in my DNS configuration for **dev.mysite.fr** on my hosting interface
2. duplicated www to www2 and make **dev.mysite.fr** to point to www2 (I made sure of it by first putting a dummy .html file in it and noticed that it was indeed redirecting to it).
3. duplicated the database and make the new installation point to it (changing the **/www2/app/config/parameters.php** file)
4. deleted all the cache of the Prestashop in /www2/app/cache and in my browser
5. Updated all the url values in all the tables
6. Deleted the **htaccess** file

Despite all this, when I type **dev.mysite.fr** in my browser it still redirect to **mysite.fr**. I am suspecting that my web host redirects to it because maybe there are some errors on **dev.mysite.fr**...

Any ideas ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I found it, nobody ever talked about it, but here is my gift to the world, in **/www2/app/config/parameters.php** change **ps_cache_enable** to false